# How to install ZeroMQ for C++ using VS2015 community

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, zeromq

I am trying to learn networking in windows in C++ (specifically for making a very simple mmo server).

I was reading about cross-platform-ness and socket complexity and came accross both protobuf and zeroMQ quite a lot.

After reading about zeroMQ I decided it makes sense for an mmo server.

So i went over to the zeroMQ website and downloaded the msi installer. I ran it, and now i'm stuck.

I don't quite understand what the MSI did... Did it plop a zeroMQ.dll in system32? Di I still need to get the C++ binding? Basically, how do you install zeromq for C++?

P.S. extra points if someone shows me how to do it with Nuget. I guess that's why I don't know how to install libraries manually, I always use Nuget...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuget does have a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZeroMQ/) for ZeroMQ, but that seems to be only for C# currently.

The MSI you installed contains Python binding for ZeroMQ, and is installed for the selected python version in the installer.

For C++, they have pre-build binaries on their [download page](http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows).
However, these libraries are build with an older version of Visual Studio, which are [not compatible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/18/c-runtime-crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1/) with Visual Studio 2015. If you want to use ZeroMQ, i'm afraid you are going to have to [build](http://zeromq.org/build:_start) the library your self.

When you have successfully build ZeroMQ, you can follow their [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) to get a feeling of how to use it. Or you can add the [C++ bindings](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq) which has a pretty and easy-to-use interface.

Comment: Ok so i cloned the git repo in your "build" link and built the sln in msvc 2015. It says in the output that it created a dll called libzmq.dll in "..\bin\Win32\Debug\v140\dynamic\libzmq.dll". Is that it? Can i just plop that dll in system 32 and include it in my projects? Is it reallt that simple???

Comment: No, building the library was the easy part. It should also have build a `.lib` file, which you should [link with your own project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx). And instead of putting the `libzmq.dll` in the Windows/System32 folder, you should put it in the same folder as your project executable.

Comment: Ok good. I'm sorry I seem so hopelessly clueless... I assume now I need to include the c++ wrapper header files in my project. The exe will know to look for the dll in it's current folder?

Comment: Yes, but make sure `libzmq/include/` can be found by the compiler. To do that, you should add the (full or relative) path to libzmq\include to the [include directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx). Windows uses a specific order to [search for DLL's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx), which contains the directory where the executable is located.

Comment: Ok, in order to avoid having to have a folder that i'll eventually forget about on my computer for the include folder(zmq.h and zmq_utils.h), is it acceptable to just dump it in my project structure and include it from there? Also, I just realized that it compiled without the reference to the lib file in the include paths... I'm so confused. If only there were a step by step guide for people who have never had to do this before... I appreciate your help.

Comment: Now that you mention it, there had to be such a guide. [And there is](https://gerrydevstory.com/2015/04/24/setting-up-zeromq-c-on-visual-studio/) (for an older version, but the steps remain pretty much the same). You can place the header files where ever you like. For me personally it would make sense to keep them with the library.

Comment: Thanks :) Instead of downloading the exe in the guide, I used the info you provided earlier to build the lib and dll files and continued from there using the guide. I think it worked but I have no code calling anything to do with zmq yet so i'll whip something up and let you know. Thanks a bunch!!